# Why is my bitmap not displaying in the ImageView?

Tags: android, image

I am trying to display a thumbnail for the user, but it is not working. If the user selects "photo", he or she takes a photo on the `MainActivity` and then the URI is passed to the `NewActivity`. Here is how I am passing the data:

this is in the `MainActivity`

```
onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)

 Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_S);
```

this is also in the `MainActivity`

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent)

 case ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO_S:
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NewActivity.class);
        Uri imageUri = intent.getData();
        i.putExtra("imageUri", imageUri.toString());
        startActivity(i);
    }
    break;
```

I am receiving this URI in the `NewActivity`

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String imageuri = extras.getString("imageUri");

        try {
            ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(imageuri));
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

here is [part of] my activity_create.xml layout (where the `ImageView` is)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="45"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/delete_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_remove"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have searched all of Stack Overflow and could not find an answer. I tried logging the "bitmap" and the "imageuri" variables from the `NewActivity` `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and got the following:

for "bitmap"

```
android.graphics.Bitmap@42feb668
```

for "imageuri"

```
content://media/external/images/media/596
```

So, I know the image is being passed correctly between the activities, but it is not displaying in the ImageView even after I set its visibility to visible.

**Edit:**

I tried manually setting my ImageView (this is on `NewActivity` line 68)

```
mImageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/596"));
```

this gave me the following errors

```
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064): Process: com.lschlessinger.myspots, PID: 32064
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:709)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:685)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:513)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:889)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromStream(Drawable.java:840)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:675)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:409)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at com.lschlessinger.myspots.NewActivity.onCreate(NewActivity.java:68)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
05-03 00:19:46.368: E/AndroidRuntime(32064):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's the size/dimension of your bitmap?

Comment: Take that string, put it in a with `Uri` object with `Uri.parse(someStr)` and use `mImageView.setImageURI(imgUri);`

Comment: @Glenn-- it is 5312 x 2988 (width x height)

Comment: @razpeitia response in edit

Comment: It can't display a bitmap more than the maximum dimension. It depends on device, E.g. `4096x4096`.

Comment: @Glenn-- You're right - I just tried changing the dimensions and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to outofmemory error it is clear that the application couldn't load bitmap from specific URI due it its size.you need resize the image if you want to load it in your app! there are multiple ways to solve this issue, you can solve it using `android:largeHeap=”true”` to application tag in manifest file.But you shouldn't do that,you should solve it by resizing the image to required size.also you can follow these solutions mentioned in these posts:

[MEMORY LEAK AND OUT OF MEMORY ERROR](http://www.shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/08/memory-leak-and-out-of-memory-error.html)

[MEMORY LEAK AND OUT OF MEMORY ERROR USING LRU CACHE](http://www.shaikhhamadali.blogspot.ro/2013/09/memory-leak-and-out-of-memory-error.html)

[MEMORY LEAK AND OUT OF MEMORY ERROR USING DISK LRU CACHE](http://www.shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/09/memory-leak-and-out-of-memory-error_3.html)

[MEMORY LEAK AND OUT OF MEMORY ERROR USING LIST,LINKEDLIST AND HASHMAP](http://www.shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/08/memory-leak-and-out-of-memory-error_29.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to handle the resizing of your bitmap yourself there are also various libraries which could do this for you. Examples would be:
https://github.com/novoda/ImageLoader#getting-the-library

There you can also dynamically set the resizing of the image to the specific dimension of the phone.